# Teradata 3706, expected something between DISTINCT and LEFT keyword

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-update, teradata

I am here trying to use UPDATE query with JOIN and SELECT, But I am facing 3706 error.

here is the error line -

[image: Teradat error]

```
UPDATE A0619IL3549_D_RPT.RPT_IS_ELIGIBILITY A2
FROM
(SELECT A.REP_CD, A.GEO_CD,A.MONTH_ID, B.IC_PRD AS IC_PAYOUT_FLAG,
COALESCE(CASE 
WHEN UPPER(B.IC_PRD) = 'SEMESTERLY' THEN A.CURR_SEMESTER_FLAG
WHEN UPPER(B.IC_PRD) = 'QUARTERLY' THEN A. CURR_QUARTER_FLAG
ELSE '0'
END,'0') IC_PAYOUT_FLAG
FROM 
A0619IL3549_D_RPT.RPT_IS_ELIGIBILITY A,
(
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(B. REP_CD, POSITION('-' IN B.REP_CD)-1) AS REP_CD,C.GEO_CD,IC_PRD FROM 
A0619IL3549_D00_IC_MAIN.ICDM_GEO_REP_PROD A, A0619IL3549_D00_IC_MAIN.ICDM_DIM_REP B,
A0619IL3549_D00_IC_MAIN.ICDM_DIM_GEO_HIER C
WHERE
A.REP_SK=B.REP_SK
AND A.GEO_SK=C.GEO_SK
AND A.RUN_ID  = (SELECT MAX(RUN_ID) FROM A0619IL3549_D00_IC_MAIN.ICDM_GEO_REP_PROD)
) B
WHERE
A.REP_CD  = B.REP_CD
AND 
A.GEO_CD = B.GEO_CD)A1
SET A2.IC_PAYOUT_FALG = A1.IC_PAYOUT_FLAG
WHERE 
A1.REP_CD = A2.REP_CD
AND
A1.MONTH_ID = A2.MONTH_ID
AND
A.GEO_CD = A2.GEO_CD
```

Comment: I am using version 13.10.0.02 , teradata SQL assistant

Comment: I guess it is not because of a space between b. and rep_cd, right?

Comment: Nope, I have removed the space and re-run, but same error.

Comment: I think it is some logical error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT` is not a valid Teradata function before TD15.10, it's ODBC SQL, which is automatically translated, but only for `SELECT`.

Use valid syntax instead:

```
SUBSTRING(B. REP_CD FROM 1 FOR POSITION('-' IN B.REP_CD)-1)
```

Comment: Hi dnoeth, Thanks a lot, that error is gone but now i see an "illegal use of alias name" error. ie error (3993)

Comment: @user2492144: Don't use an alias (`A2`), use `RPT_IS_ELIGIBILITY` instead

Comment: dnoeth, Alias error is gone but now again 3810 has occurred, which says colum/parameter 'A0619IL3549_D_RPT.RPT_IS_ELIGIBILTY.A0619IL3549_D_RPT' dose not exists

Comment: I have replaced all A2s with A0619IL3549_D_RPT.RPT_IS_ELIGIBILITY

Comment: please have a look,I still cannot run this query, can I use Merge here ??

Comment: @user2492144: I'm not a syntax parser :) There's just one thing: No table name in SET: `SET IC_PAYOUT_FALG = A1.IC_PAYOUT_FLAG`. And please start using better aliases instead of `a`,`a1`,`a2`,`b`...

Comment: I understand , Thanks a lot :)